# ArcGIS for Server need an Administrator account for Manager Account 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

Please log on to ArcGIS Server manager with an account "ArcGIS\localhost" and I acceded to ArcGIS manager I can not use the functionality I resent a message that I need an administrative account And also when I try to publish from ArcMap I receive not the option to display.

[image]
I have : ArcGIS 10.0
             ArcGIS Server 10.0
             Windows 7

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What is your question?  Are you the ArcGIS Server administrator?  You create a login when you install ArcGIS Server - use that to log in.  Please **[edit]** the question to include more information.

Comment: If you are not the ArcGIS Server administrator, then you need to contact them to get a login for your server.

Comment: the problem is that the account I created with arcgis server "account name : localhost" and "passe word : 124563" so now when i want to do my first application they said that i need an administrator account and i don't know what is this administrator name !

Comment: Please re-open this. The question is clear enough if you remember ArcGIS 10.0 server.

Comment: where can i find the administrator account please ?

Comment: cross posted from https://geonet.esri.com/thread/195067-arcgis-for-server-need-an-administrator-account-for-manager-account-100 you have to assign admin to localhost via ArcGIS\localhost is added to AGSADMIN

Answer (score 4):

To login to ArcGIS Server Manager in 9.3-10.0, you need to have the account assigned to the proper windows group that gets created during the install; `agsadmin`. This [help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000000n4000000) explains further. Specifically you can have an account in one of the following groups depending on your connection scenario:

```
When you open Manager, you will be prompted to log in. You must use an account that is:
A member of the agsadmin group on the server object manager (SOM) machine.
A member of the agsusers group on any machines to which you will make an ArcGIS Server local connection.
A member of the Administrators group on the Web server machine (only required if you will be using Manager to create Web applications).
```

This is explained in the [setup instructions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Configuring_a_one_machine_deployment/0093000000m6000000/) as well.

Based on your question, it looks like you might be confusing "localhost", how you refer to the computer itself with a windows account.

Comment: Hello there I will show you more detail to know where is the problemWhen installing the arcgis server I was led to create 3 account; A SOM account (arcSOM) a SOC account (arcSOC) and name of the arcgis server (arcabdelwajid) but I do not know what account name worked, e.g I'm trying to acess with this account arcgisserver \ arcSOM with a word of Pass to connect to the manager it say that this account does not have administrative access yet I added these 3 account in agsusers and agsadmin, I keep looking how to have this account that will allow me to create an application administrative account